# Why is ROOT_URL a required environment variable for bundle deployment?

Tags: meteor

I have my Meteor app serving for a number of domains. The app's functionality is the same for all sites, but the host names dictate which templates I render.

Everything works fine when I run my Meteor app in production with ROOT_URL pointing to only one of the domains. So I'm wondering, *why is this a required environment variable* other than for its use in `Meteor.absoluteUrl()`? (which I personally don't use though I recognize it may be used elsewhere under the hood)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of this in production environments is during OAuth callbacks. If you log in via Facebook/Twitter/Google or some other third party it will call back to your domain and your browser has to route this correctly.

In OAuth the domain used must match the one given to the other side for security. The other is so that the OAuth login provider, like facebook knows where to redirect back to.

So this is passed on through the `ROOT_URL`. e.g for facebook when logging in would redirect back to `Meteor.absoluteUrl('_oauth/facebook?close')`

Comment: Great answer, makes sense. I guess I need to look into using the `Meteor.absoluteUrl()` `ROOT_URL` override option  in conjunction with OAuth in order to get it to work across all domains? I've dug through the OAuth package a bit and can't find their implementation for that.

Comment: Nevermind, found it in each Account package lib & client implementation. Thanks for your help

Comment: Also, on prod ROOT_URL is used to prefix the URL path for things like email confirmations templates and so on

Comment: @WesJohnson Mind sharing the code in a fiddle? I guess you customized the accounts package?