# accounts-facebook fails with SecurityError when the site uses SSL

Tags: facebook, ssl, meteor, meteor-accounts

My meteor app has so far lived "unsecured" - meaning no redirection to https:// by default. This has worked fine in conjunction with the accounts-facebook package, which creates its own SSL enabled connection to Facebook when doing its OAuth magic.

My problems started when I tried acessing my site using https instead of http. The pop-up window the accounts package opens to log into facebook halts quickly and by reading its console output I can see the following message

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://wishlist-foobar.meteor.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://wishlist-foobar.meteor.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.`

I thought this might have something to do with the site url in the app's facebook settings, but changing the http to https in that setting got me nowhere. Still got the same message. How is this supposed to work? I am not hardcoding the http part of the path anywhere except the facebook settings, so this seems to be something the accounts-facebook package is doing.

This is my app settings on Facebook. Observe the non-SSL site url. 
[image]

Comment: bounce, bounce, baby...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you need to set the ROOT_URL environment variable for the callbacks to work and make sure visitors hit that url (for instance, forcing ssl). See these SO answers for more background info.

- [Google OAuth login in http server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640669/google-oauth-login-in-https-server)
- [Why is ROOT_URL a required environment variable for bundle deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387268/why-is-root-url-a-required-environment-variable-for-bundle-deployment?rq=1)