# google Oauth login in https server

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-oauth

I have an meteor web server on Https server say `https://popasdesasdasd.com`.
I added this url to the Javascript Origin uri and `https://popasdesasdasd.com/_oauth/google?close` in redirect uri.

On request, it says mismatch uri and asked to put `http://popasdesasdasd.com/_oauth/google?close` in redirect uri.

Adding that gives me an error of

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin 
>       "'http://popasdesasdasd.com'" from accessing a frame with origin 
>       "' https://popasdesasdasd.com'".
>         The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http",
>       the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Redirect uril must be an exact path to a file. Example:  Https://popasdesasdasd.com/_oauth/google.php   not just a directory and it cant have any ?paramaters  after.

Comment: I am developing a meteorjs app, so I don't know of any file that should be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your ROOT_URL environment variable uses `https://` too. The one without http**s** is the reason your instructions said to use `http://popasdesasdasd.com/_oauth/google?close` as your redirect uri on Google's api console.

Also, make sure `https://popasdesasdasd.com/_oauth/google?close` is set to your redirect URI. You would have to correct the one you've already used.

If you're using an iframe this is likely to be an issue you you will need to stick to one protocol. The `force-ssl` package can help redirect all users to use SSL:

```
meteor add force-ssl
```

(Note this will make it difficult locally if you test on a VM, particularly if you use windows and the VM is seperate)

Comment: Thanks dude you are awesome. The ROOT_URL was the issue